# drop event isn't passed down correctly on Edge

Tags: angular, typescript, microsoft-edge

I've got a webpage with a draggable table in which you can drag and drop items to move them in order.

On Chrome and Firefox, this is working flawlessly but for some reason, I can't seem to get it to work in Edge.

When I debug on Edge all properties of the event object that is passed down are Errors.

[image]

Here is my code:

TypeScript

```
dragEnd(event) {
event.target.style.opacity = '1';
}

drag(event, questionId: number) {
event.dataTransfer.setData('questionId', questionId);
const element: HTMLTableRowElement = event.target;
element.style.opacity = '0.4';
}

allowDrop(ev) {
ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
ev.preventDefault();
}

drop(event, themeId: number) {
const target = event.target.parentElement;
this.moveRow(Number(event.dataTransfer.getData('questionId')), this.stripCharacters(target.id));
this.updateSaveOrderButton(themeId);
}

 moveRow(source: number, target: number) {
let questions: Question[] = this.evaluation.themes.find
  (t => t.id === this.getQuestionById(source).theme_id).questions;

const sourceIndex: number = questions.findIndex(q => q.evaluation_question_id === source);
const targetIndex: number = questions.findIndex(q => q.evaluation_question_id === target);

if (questions.find(q => q.evaluation_question_id === target) && sourceIndex !== targetIndex)
  questions = this.arrayMove(questions, sourceIndex, targetIndex);

}}
```

HTML

```
 <tr [id]="'questionrow' + question.evaluation_question_id" *ngFor="let question of theme.questions; let index = index"
                class="draggable" draggable="true" (dragend)="dragEnd($event)" (drop)="drop($event, theme.id)"
                (dragstart)="drag($event, question.evaluation_question_id)" (dragover)="allowDrop($event)">
```

Comment: Did you see any error in console? If possible then can you post a jsfiddle example. so that we can directly make a test with Edge to check for the issue.

Comment: First two while starting to drag.
Last two are from the function that gets the wrong parameters due to the first 2 errors.

ERROR Error: Invalid argument.
ERROR CONTEXT [object Object]

ERROR TypeError: Unable to get property 'template_questions' of undefined or null reference
ERROR CONTEXT [object Object]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer.

Apparently Edge is a bit stricter when it comes to types than other browsers.
The drag methods should have their event parameters with the type DragEvent.

Comment: Can you provide an example please?